# Can I write into Google Chrome Url Address bar using an extention ?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I create a Google chrome extension to change the URL of Google Chrome URL address bar?

Example :  If I wrote in the address bar شةثقثىشغشزؤؤخة by wrong, it detects the letters and convert them into English letter to to : amerenaya.com

Comment: You can already do this with international domain names using puny code. For example if you enter go to http://شةثقثىشغشزؤؤخة.com in a modern browser it will convert that to http://www.xn--jgbanchax3aoda5e7ete.com/ under the hood for you.

Comment: I need to do when I write /شةثقثىشغشزؤؤخة it is converted into amerenaya.com in the bar, based on the correspondence letters of keyboard

Comment: Chrome extensions can provide search engines - the 1Password extension does this. You could create an extension search engine and set that as your default search engine.

Comment: Noooo, I mean 

Suppose I wrote ش in the address bar it corresponds A in the keyboard so I need to be changed into A

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that, since the architecture of extensions is based somewhat on URL-based permissions for extensions, and you'd need to hook into earlier stuff than that. But what have you tried so far, and which parts of the extensions documentation have been the most promising?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to changes in the URL's of the tab using the `onUpdated` [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) then you need to determine if there is a litteral keyboard translation and then reload the tab using the `update` [method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update), unfortunately this will cause the page to reload, but it gets you partially to your solution.